# Emacs incorrectly wraps text with fill-paragraph

Tags: emacs, word-wrap

So in Emacs, word-wraping is called filling and is done by `M-q` or `M-x fill-paragraph`. Is there any way to modify this function to respect spaces that should be non-breaking? For example, if we have the following sentence:

```
This is a black sentence with a yellow word at the end.
```

and tell Emacs to fill-paragraph at mark 50, it wraps it like this:

```
This is a black sentence with a yellow word at the
end.
```

However, if I do the same with `C-u M-x shell-command-on-region` and enter `fold -sw 50`, I get the following (correct) output:

```
This is a black sentence with a yellow word at 
the end.
```

A similar problem happens when the end of a sentence is followed by something in parentheses:

```
This is a black sentence with a yellow word here. (This is something in parens)
```

The above sentence is wrapped with `M-q` at mark 50 in the following way:

```
This is a black sentence with a yellow word
here. (This is something in parens)
```

However, `fold -sw 50` wraps it correctly:

```
This is a black sentence with a yellow word here. 
(This is something in parens)
```

I know I could just write a function that uses `fold` and use that but I'm curious as to why `fill-paragraph` behaves like this and if it can be modified.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not sure what your definition of "non-breaking" space is.

However, you can achieve what you want in your examples by doing:

```
(add-to-list 'fill-nobreak-predicate 'fill-single-word-nobreak-p)
(setq sentence-end-double-space nil)
```

Documentation (and comment) of `fill-single-word-nobreak-p` says:

```
"Don't break a line after the first or before the last word of a sentence."
;; Actually, allow breaking before the last word of a sentence, so long as
;; it's not the last word of the paragraph.
```

You can add your own predicates to the `fill-nobreak-predicate` list.

Comment: Nice, that solves the second problem of breaking before a paren. Not really sure about the definition of a non-breaking space but `fold` does it right. That is, for example, a "the" should never be the last word on a line. I've come across different examples as well but can't think of then right now.

Comment: If you know the rules you want, it is easy to implement them in emacs as additional predicate/s (there are some of those around already, search for nobreak emacs).  If you don't know what you want it is harder to find a solution.

Comment: By the way, I find very funny the fact that man page for fold in here http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?fold has three "the" as last word of a line :-)

Comment: Ok, I'll have a look at the predicates. Thank you! And fyi, the official man page that is displayed when you execute `man fold` does not wrap anything so no trailing "the"s :-)